# phpcassa Schema

Tags: php, cassandra

```
create column family PwdUrl with 
    default_validation_class=UTF8Type and key_validation_class=UTF8Type and 
    comparator =UTF8Type and 
    column_metadata = [ {
        column_name:createdAt, 
        validation_class:UTF8Type, 
        index_type: KEYS
    },{
        column_name:expireAt, 
        validation_class:UTF8Type, 
        index_type: KEYS}
    ]
```

This is the schema I need to set up. Is it possible to do this using phpcassa? If not, what other options are there?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can do this with just phpcassa.  You'll use the [SystemManager](http://thobbs.github.com/phpcassa/api/phpcassa/sysmanager/SystemManager.html) class.  Here's an example:

```
<?php
require_once('phpcassa/sysmanager.php');

$sys = SystemManager("localhost:9160");
$my_keyspace = "Keyspace1";
$cfattrs = array("column_type" => "Standard",
                 "comparator_type" => "UTF8Type",
                 "default_validation_class" => "UTF8Type",
                 "key_validation_class" => "UTF8Type");
$sys->create_column_family($my_keyspace, "PwdUrl", $cfattrs);
$sys->create_index($my_keyspace, "PwdUrl", "createdAt", "UTF8Type");
$sys->create_index($my_keyspace, "PwdUrl", "expireAt", "UTF8Type");
$sys->close();
?>
```

Comment: hi Do u have any idea about Nodejs with solandra connection.

Comment: No. Please create a new post if you have a different question.